# How to find the asymptotics of a linear two-dimensional recurrence relation

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, recurrences

Let $d$ be a positive number.
There is a two dimensional recurrence relation as follow:
$$R(n,m) = R(n-1,m-1) + R(n,m-d)$$
where
$R(0,m) = 1$ and $R(n,0) = R(n,1) = \cdots = R(n, d-1) = 1$ for all $n,m>0$.

How to analyze the asymptotics of $R(n, kn)$ for fixed $k$?
It is easy to see that
$$R(n, kn) = O\left( c_{k,d}^{n} \cdot (n+k+d)^{O(1)} \right)$$
Is there a way (or an algorithm) to find $c_{k,d}$ given $k$ and $d$?

PS: I have calcuated the bivariate generating function of $R(\cdot, \cdot)$:
\begin{align}
f(x,y) 
&= \frac{1 - xy - y^{d} + xy^{d}}{(1 - x)(1 - y)(1 - xy - y^{d})} \\
&= \frac{1}{(1 - x)(1 - y)} + \frac{xy^{d}}{(1 - x)(1 - y)(1 - xy - y^{d})} \\
\end{align}

Comment: For $k=1$ the gf seems to be $\frac1{1-t-t^d}$, right?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  You mean the generating function of $T(n) = R(n, n)$? I am not sure.

Comment: Experimentally this seems so. Also, for $d=1$ it seems that $R(n,kn)=\sum_{j\leqslant n}\binom{kn}j$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes, that is right, there was a question when $d=1$, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2065067/solving-two-dimensional-recurrence-relation-a-i-j-a-i-j-1-a-i

Comment: If you add $y-y$ to the numerator of $f$ you can split it into $$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{(1 - x)(1 - xy - y^d)} + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{d-1} y^i}{1 - xy - y^d}$$ The second term is easy to extract coefficients from, but the first one is messy.

Comment: More generally,$$R(n,m)=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{\left[\frac{m-j+1}d\right]+j-1}j$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your generating function $f(x,y)$ is convergent on a polydisk $|x|<\epsilon$, $|y|< \delta$, for some $\epsilon, \delta < 1$. We can reduce $\epsilon$ so that $\epsilon \ll \delta^k$ and the domain of $f(x,y)$ to the product of the polydisk $|x|<\epsilon$ and the annulus $\delta' < |y| < \delta$, with $\delta' \sim \delta$. Then $g(z,y) = f(z/y^k, y)$ is well-defined and analytic on the product domain of $|z|\lesssim \epsilon/\delta^k$ and $\delta' < |y| < \delta$. The generating function $g(z,y)$ has a unique expansion that is a power series in $z$ and a Laurent series in $y$. Since $x^n y^m = (z/y^k)^n y^m = z^n y^{m-kn}$, the coefficients $R(n,kn)$ are the coefficients of $z^n y^0$ in this double expansion. Hence, using the Cauchy integral formula, the generating function for $R(n,kn)$ is now given by the contour integral
$$
  \sum_{n=0}^\infty R(n,kn) z^n = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{|y|\sim \delta} g(z,y) \frac{dy}{y} .
$$
Of course, the integration contour is now allowed to deform, as long as it doesn't hit any singularities of the integrand.

The above integrand has a convenient partial fraction expansion expansion with respect to $z$,
$$
  \frac{g(z,y)}{y} = \frac{y^k}{(1-y-y^d)(y^k-z)}
    - \frac{y^{d+k-1}(1-y^d)}{(1-y)(1-y-y^d) (y^{k-1} (1-y^d)-z)} .
$$
Expanding in $z$ under the integral gives the formula
$$
  R(n,kn) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{dy}{y^{kn} (1-y-y^d)}
    - \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{y^d dy}{(1-y)(1-y-y^d) y^{n(k-1)} (1-y^d)^n} ,
$$
whose leading asymptotics can be estimated by residues or steepest descent.

Using residues on the first term, all the contributions come from the roots of $1-y-y^d=0$. The root with the smallest magnitude $y_*$ will give the leading contribution. Some experimentation shows that $y_*$ is the unique positive real root. The leading asymptotic term then looks like
$$
  C_* y_*^{-kn} .
$$
In the special case $d=1$, $y_* = 1/2$. In the special case $k=1$, the second term has no poles inside its contour and hence evaluates to zero. So in the sequel we can assume that $k>1$.

Applying [steepest descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_steepest_descent) to the second integral, we find the stationary phase points at the roots $y_\star$ of $y^d = (k-1)/(k+d-1) + O(1/n)$. Let $y_\star$ be that root (actually we just need its $n\to \infty$ limit) which minimizes the magnitude of $y_\star^{k-1} (1-y_\star^d)$. It is easy too see that $y_\star = \sqrt[d]{(k-1)/(d+k-1)}$. Then the leading asymptotic term is
$$
  C_\star n^{-1/2} y_\star^{-n(k-1)} (1-y_\star^d)^{-n}
  = C_\star n^{-1/2} w_\star^{-kn} ,
$$
where $w_\star = \left(\frac{k-1}{d+k-1}\right)^{\frac{1-1/k}{d}} \left(\frac{d}{d+k-1}\right)^{1/k} = \frac{s^{s/k}}{(s+1)^{(s+1)/k}}$ with $s=(k-1)/d$, as pointed out in the comments.

The conclusion is that
$$
  R(n,kn) = O\left((\min(y_*,w_\star)^{-k})^n\right) .
$$

Experimentation suggests that $y_* < w_\star$ in all cases, except for $(k,d)=(2,1)$, when $y_* = w_\star = 1/2$. Otherwise the $y_*$ contribution always seems to dominate over the $w_\star$ contribution. At least that's how it seemed for not too large values of $d$.

Doing some rudimentary asymptotic calculations for large $d$, it seems that $y_* \sim 1- \frac{\log d}{d} + o(\log(d)/d)$. A better approximation is
$$
  y_* \sim 1 - \frac{W(d)}{d} + \frac{W(d)^3}{2(W(d)+1) d^2} + O(W(d)^3/d^3) ,
$$
where $W(d)$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). On the other hand, $w_\star$ has a minimum as a function of $k$ (treating it as a continuous variable) around $k_\star \sim W(d) + 1 + O(W(d)^2/d)$, the minimum reaches roughly
$$
   w_\star \sim 1 - \frac{W(d)}{d-1}  \lesssim y_* .
$$
One should push the asymptotics of $k_\star$ one more order to get a better estimate of the difference, but experiments do show that the minimum of $w_\star$ does dip below $y_*$, for instance this happens near $(k,d) = (5, 205)$ or $(6,700)$. So it looks like the $w_\star$ asymptotic contribution will dominate in small ranges of $k \sim k_\star(d)$ if it happens to fall near an integer. To get the size of that window, one could go to a quadratic Taylor approximation of $w_\star$.

With a bit of extra work, one could also extract the coefficients $C_*$ and $C_\star$ from the integral formula.

Comment: Thanks, I mean the asymptotics is $C^{n} \cdot n^{O(1)}$. I am considering the exact expression of $C$ which depends on $k$ and $d$ only.

Comment: @Blanco I see, my bad. Sorry, I missed the exponent $n$ on your $c_{k,d}^n$. Then this approach suggests that the largest of $y_*^{-k}$ and $y_\star^{-k} (1-y_\star^d)^{-1}$ is the base of the leading exponential asymptotic.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very well explained. The root of $1-y-y^d$ makes sense, since it is the characteristic equation of the linear 1-dimensional recurrence relation of $R(n) = R(n-1) + R(n-d)$. As for the second root, how to caluate it, does it mean $y_{\star} = \sqrt[d]{(k-1)/(k+d-1)}$?

Comment: @Blanco Yes, that's right.

Comment: According to Iosif Pinelis's and my results, the second base should be $y_{\star}^{-(k-1)} \cdot (1 - y_{\star}^d)^{-1}$ which is equal to $(s+1)^{s+1}/s^s$ where $s = (k-1)/d$. Do I miss something?

Comment: @Blanco No :-), you just noticed that I miscopied part of the last formula with integrals, which itself should be correct. Yes, the second exponential base should be $y_{\star}^{-(k-1)} \cdot (1 - y_{\star}^d)^{-1}$, which agrees with your other formula. I'm glad that our conclusions agree in the end! Later I'll try to fix up the body of my answer according to this discussion.

Comment: Comparing with the linear 1-dimensional recurrence relation $T(n)=T(n−1)+T(n−d)$, it is easy to see that $T(kn) \geq R(n, kn)$, thus $T(kn) = O(y_{*}^{-kn})$ implies that $R(n, kn) = O(y_{*}^{-kn})$. But it is a little strange for me to believe that $R(n,kn) = \Omega(y_{*}^{-kn})$ holds for large enough $k$.

Comment: @Blanco In the end, I found a surprisingly subtle condition on $(k,d)$ for which the dominant asymptotic terms switch between $y_*$ and $w_\star$.

Answer (score 2):

This is to complement Blanco's answer by showing that
\begin{equation*}
    R(n,kn)=\exp\{(C_{k,d}+o(1))\,n\} \tag{0}\label{0}
\end{equation*}
(as $n\to\infty$), where $k\ge1$ and $d\ge1$ (are fixed),
\begin{equation*}
    C_{k,d}:=\frac k{1+y_{k,d}\,d}\,\big(\ln(1+y_{k,d})+y_{k,d}\,\ln(1+1/y_{k,d})\big),
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    y_{k,d}:=\max\Big(x_d,\frac{k-1}d\Big), 
\end{equation*}
and $x_d$ is the unique positive root of the equation
\begin{equation*}
    x_d(1+x_d)^{d-1}=1. \tag{0.5}\label{0.5}
\end{equation*}

In view of Blanco's answer, it is enough to show that
\begin{equation*}
    B(n):=B(n,kn)=\exp\{(C_{k,d}+o(1))\,n\}, \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    B(n):=\max\{c_{a,b}\colon (a,b)\in E_{n,k,d}\},
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    E_{n,k,d}:=\{(a,b)\colon 0\le a\le n-1,b\ge0,bd+a\le kn-d,\ a,b \text{ are integers}\},
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    c_{a,b}:=\binom{a+b}b=\binom{a+b}a. 
\end{equation*}
Note that $c_{a,b}$ is increasing in $a$ and in $b$.

Note also that $c_{a,b}=(a+b)^{O(1)}=n^{O(1)}$ for $(a,b)\in E_{n,k,d}$ if $a=O(1)$ or $b=O(1)$.

So, it remains to consider the case when $a\to\infty$ and $b\to\infty$. Then, by Stirling's formula,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    \ln c_{a,b}\sim a\ln(1+b/a)+b\ln(1+a/b). 
\end{aligned}
\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}

Also,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    \frac{c_{a+d,b-1}}{c_{a,b}}&=b\frac{(a+d+1)\cdots(a+d+b-1)}{(a+1)\cdots(a+b)} \\ 
    &= b\frac{(a+b+1)\cdots(a+b+d-1)}{(a+1)\cdots(a+d)} \\ 
    &\sim b\frac{(a+b)^{d-1}}{a^d} =\frac ba\Big(1+\frac ba\Big)^{d-1}. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
So, for a fixed value of $bd+a$, the maximum of $c_{a,b}$ occurs when $b/a\to x_d$ (recall \eqref{0.5}).

Let now $(a,b)\in E_{n,k,d}$ be a maximizer of $c_{a,b}$ (such that $a\to\infty$ and $b\to\infty$). Then, since $c_{a,b}$ is increasing in $a$ and in $b$, we have
\begin{equation*}
    bd+a\sim kn. 
\end{equation*}

The conditions $b/a\to x_d$ and $bd+a\sim kn$ imply
\begin{equation*}
a\sim k\frac1{1+x_d\,d}\,n, \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation*}
and the latter condition is compatible with condition $a\le n-1$ only if
\begin{equation*}
    k\frac1{1+x_d\,d}\le1. \tag{4}\label{4} 
\end{equation*}

If this is the case, then
\begin{equation*}
b\sim k\frac{x_d}{1+x_d\,d}\,n, 
\end{equation*}
so that, by \eqref{2},
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    \frac{\ln c_{a,b}}n\to \frac k{1+x_d\,d}\,(\ln(1+x_d)+x_d\,\ln(1+1/x_d)). 
\end{aligned}
\tag{5}\label{5}
\end{equation*}
Also, \eqref{4} implies $x_d\ge(k-1)/d$, so that $y_{k,d}=x_d$.
So, we have proved \eqref{1}, and thus \eqref{0} -- in the case when condition (3) is compatible with condition $a\le n-1$.

Otherwise, we have $a=n-1\sim n$ and still $bd+a\sim kn$, whence $b\sim(k-1)n/d$. So, by \eqref{2}, here
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    \frac{\ln c_{a,b}}n\to \ln\Big(1+\frac{k-1}d\Big)+\frac{k-1}d\,\ln\Big(1+\frac d{k-1}\Big). 
\end{aligned}
\tag{6}\label{6}
\end{equation*}
Also, in this "incompatibility" case, we have $k\frac1{1+x_d\,d}\ge1$ -- cf. \eqref{4}. So, here $x_d\le(k-1)/d$ and hence $y_{k,d}=\frac{k-1}d$.
So, we have proved \eqref{1}, and thus \eqref{0} -- in the case when condition (3) is incompatible with condition $a\le n-1$.

Thus, in either case, \eqref{0} is proved. $\quad\Box$

Answer (score 2):

The book [Analytic Combinatorics in Several Variables](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Epemantle/ACSV.pdf) by Pemantle and Wilson covers problems like this extensively.

Answer (score 1):

This is a part of my approach, and I have not finished.

Firstly,
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-y)} = \sum_{i,j \geq 0} x^{i}y^{j}
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{1 - xy - y^{d}} = \sum_{i \geq 0} \frac{x^{i}y^{i}}{(1 - y^{d})^{i + 1}} = 
\sum_{i, j \geq 0} \binom{i + j}{j} x^{i}y^{jd + i}$$

Thus
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(1 - x)(1 - y)(1 - xy - y^{d})}
= &\left( \sum_{i,j \geq 0} x^{i}y^{j} \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{i, j \geq 0} \binom{i + j}{j} x^{i}y^{jd + i} \right) \\
= &\sum_{i,j \geq 0} \sum_{a \leq i, bd + a \leq j} \binom{a + b}{b} x^{i}y^{j}  \\
\end{align}
We have
$$f(x, y) = \sum_{i,j \geq 0} \left( 1 + \sum_{a \leq i - 1, bd + a \leq j - d} \binom{a + b}{b} \right) x^{i}y^{j}$$
and
$$R(n, m) = 1 + \sum_{a + 1 \leq n, (b + 1)d + a \leq m} \binom{a + b}{b}$$

---

Let
$$B(n,m) = \max_{a + 1 \leq n, (b + 1)d + a \leq m} \binom{a + b}{b}$$
then we have
$$B(n,m) \leq R(n,m) \leq nmB(n,m)$$
Thus $R(n, m) = O(B(n,m))\cdot (nm)^{O(1)}$